# cython cdef class c method: how to call it from another cython cdef class without python overhead?

Tags: python, class, interface, cython

I am trying to implement a generic sorting algorithm in cython. So, I created the following module which implements the Heapsort algorithm inside the class `sorter_t`:

```
# file general_sort_c.pyx

from libc.stdint cimport int32_t
cdef bint bint_true = 1
cdef bint bint_false = 0

cdef class sorter_t:

    cdef object sortable_object

    def __init__(self,sortable_object):
        self.sortable_object = sortable_object

    cpdef sort_c(self):

        """
        https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort

        """

        cdef int32_t end
        cdef int32_t count = self.sortable_object.num_elements_int32

        self.heapify_c(count)

        end = count-1 
        while end > 0:
            self.sortable_object.swap_c(0,end)
            end = end - 1
            self.siftDown_c(0,end)

    cdef heapify_c(self,int32_t count):

        cdef int32_t start = (count - 2)/2   

        while start >= 0:
            self.siftDown_c(start, count-1)
            start -= 1

    cdef siftDown_c(self,int32_t start, int32_t end):

        cdef int32_t root = start
        cdef int32_t swap
        cdef int32_t child

        while root * 2 + 1 <= end:

            child = root * 2 + 1 
            swap = root

            # if "swap" < "child" then ...
            if self.sortable_object.lt_c(swap,child) == 1:
                swap = child

            if child+1 <= end and self.sortable_object.lt_c(swap,child+1) == 1:
                swap = child + 1

            if swap != root:
                self.sortable_object.swap_c(root,swap)
                root = swap
            else:
                return
```

When you define an object of type `sorter_t` you must provide a `sortable_object` which has its own particular implementations of the cdef functions `lt_c` (for comparing if one element is smaller than the other) and `swap_c` (for swapping elements).

For instance, the following code will define and create a `sortable_object` from a list, and will test the implementation of "sorter_t" using that `sortable_object`.

```
import numpy
cimport numpy
from libc.stdint cimport int32_t
import general_sort_c

cdef class sortable_t:

    cdef public int32_t num_elements_int32
    cdef int32_t [:] mv_lista

    def __init__(self,int32_t [:] mv_lista):
        self.num_elements_int32 = mv_lista.shape[0]
        self.mv_lista = mv_lista

    cdef public bint lt_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right):
        if self.mv_lista[left] < self.mv_lista[right]:
            return 1 # True
        else:
            return 0 # False

    cdef public bint gt_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right):
        if self.mv_lista[left] > self.mv_lista[right]:
            return 1 # True
        else:
            return 0 # False

    cdef public swap_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right):
        cdef int32_t tmp
        tmp = self.mv_lista[right]
        self.mv_lista[right] = self.mv_lista[left]
        self.mv_lista[left] = tmp

def probar():

    lista = numpy.array([3,4,1,7],dtype=numpy.int32)
    cdef int32_t [:] mv_lista = lista

    cdef sortable = sortable_t(mv_lista)
    cdef sorter = general_sort_c.sorter_t(sortable)
    sorter.sort_increasing_c()
    print list(lista)
```

After compiling both `.pyx` files and running following commands in an IPython console, the following error emerges:

```
In [1]: import test_general_sort_c as tgs

In [2]: tgs.probar()      

...

 general_sort_c.sorter_t.siftDown_increasing_c (general_sort_c.c:1452)()
    132 
    133             #if mv_tnet_time[swap] < mv_tnet_time[child]:

--> 134             if self.sortable_object.lt_c(swap,child) == bint_true:
    135                 swap = child
    136 

AttributeError: 'test_general_sort_c.sortable_t' object has no attribute 'lt_c'
```

So, the problem is that the implementation of the function `lt_c` is not visible from the code in module `general_sort_c.pyx`. If I define the function `lt_c` using `cpdef` instead of `cdef` it will work, but then you have a lot of Python overhead. How to call this function in a `cdef` ("pure C") way?

Comment: I want to add some comments. The code above will not work properly because the heapsort code is not good. I reimplemented the thing using quicksort algorithm. Also, this code is a simplification of a more complicated code and some inconsistencies may arise if you try it. Anyway, I believe that the general idea was understood. Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately I'm not sure how to get this to work with fused types but the rest is quite simple:

`test_general_sort_c.pyx` needs a complimentary `test_general_sort_c.pxd`:

```
from libc.stdint cimport int32_t

cdef class sortable_t:
    cdef public int32_t num_elements_int32
    cdef int32_t [:] mv_lista
    cdef public bint lt_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right)
    cdef public bint gt_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right)
    cdef public swap_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right)
```

`general_sort_c.pyx` must then `cimport` `test_general_sort_c` and type its `self.sortable_object` to be a `test_general_sort_c.sortable_t`.

This would be much better, of course, if you could have a multitude of supported types. I'm not sure how you'd do it as of now, though.

---

Also, the builtin `True` and `False` work fine on their own.

If you trusted Cython a bit more you'd realise you can write

```
cdef public bint lt_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right):
    return self.mv_lista[left] < self.mv_lista[right]

cdef public bint gt_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right):
    return self.mv_lista[left] > self.mv_lista[right]

cdef public swap_c(self, int32_t left, int32_t right):
    self.mv_lista[right], self.mv_lista[left] = self.mv_lista[left], self.mv_lista[right]
```

just fine. :)

Comment: Thanks Veedrac, it worked :). One question. In your approach general_sort_c cimport test_general_sort_c which has the particular implementations for swap_c and lt_c. Is this compatible with a general  sortable objet type? What if I have more than one sortable object type? Best Regards.

Comment: AFAIK the only solution is subclassing. Make a superclass that all files "agree" on, accept an instance of that class and make the sortable objects inherit from that. It's not Python-level dynamic but remember that we're compiling to C.